# getting error : Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-bootstrap-modal'. in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am new here in reactjs, I have installed `npm install react-bootstrap-modal` 
When i used it with `var Modal = require('react-bootstrap-modal')` , it gives me error below, can anyone please help me what i need to do in that ?

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-bootstrap-modal'. 'd:/wamp64/www/my-app/node_modules/react-bootstrap-modal/lib/Modal.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.Try `npm install @types/react-bootstrap-modal` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-bootstrap-modal';` [7016]

Try `npm install @types/react-bootstrap-modal` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-bootstrap-modal';` [7016]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The scoped type definition is not installed for react-bootstrap-modal
Try installing them:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node 
npm install --save @types/react-bootstrap
```

> Typed version of packages are maintained by DefinitelyTyped, an
>   open source community. (For Typescript 2.0+)
>   https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped